# Insertar registro de 3 tablas al mismo tiempo en MySQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, consola, insert

Buen dia,

Como realizo una inserción en MySQL Workbench, al ejecutar en consola se inserten los 3 registros en sus tablas. Al ejecutar solo me registra la primera tabla, generando error en las demás.

```
INSERT into   Equipos (ID_Equipos,Nombre,Ciudad,Web)
values (1, 'Reasdsl Barcelona', 'Barcelona', 'http://www.fcbarcelona.com/web/index_idiomes.html'),
(2,'Real Masdsddrid', 'Madrid', 'http://www.realmadrid.com/cs/Satellite/es/1193040472450/SubhomeEquipo/Baloncesto.htm'),
(3, 'Caja Socisdsdal', 'Valencia', 'http://www.valenciabasket.com/');


INSERT INTO Jugadores (id_Jugadores,FK_id_Equipos,Nombre,Apellido,Puesto,Altura,Salario)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Carlos', 'Perez', 'Alero', '210 cms', '5.000.000'),
 (2, 1, 'Pedro', 'José', 'Roa', 'Base', '198 cms','7.000.000'),
 (3, 2, 'Mario', 'Duarte', 'Pivot', '205 cms', '6.000.000'),
 (4, 2, 'Pedro', 'Franco', 'Escolta', '195 cms','6.000.000'),
 (5, 1, 'Armando', 'Mendoza', 'Alta-Pivot', '200 cms','7.500.000');



INSERT INTO Partidos (ID_Partido,Fecha,ID_Equipo_Visitante,Marcador_Equipo_Local,Marcador_Equipo_Visitante,ID_Equipo_Ganador)
VALUES 
 (1, '2019-10-12', 1, 2, 98, 97, 1),
 (2, '2019-12-14', 3, 1, 107, 105, 3), 
 (3, '2019-12-18', 2, 3, 98, 90, 2);
```

Comment: revisaste que todos los campos sean correctos??. Agrega el error que te sale

Answer (score 0):

De pronto el error es que en el tercer INSERT tiene **6 columnas** pero en los **VALUES tienes 7**, de no ser así puedes indicar cual es el error.

- En el segundo Insert podemos observar que tiene 7 columnas pero 8 values
  (2, 1, 'Pedro', 'José', 'Roa', 'Base', '198 cms','7.000.000')

Comment: Ya realice esa corrección en la 3 tabla, este es el error:

21:52:17 INSERT INTO Jugadores (ID_Jugadores,ID_Equipos,Nombre,Apellido,Puesto,Altura,Salario) VALUES (1, 1, 'Carlos', 'Perez', 'Alero', '210 cms', '5.000.000'),  (2, 1, 'Pedro', 'José', 'Roa', 'Base', '198 cms','7.000.000'),  (3, 2, 'Mario', 'Duarte', 'Pivot', '205 cms', '6.000.000'),  (4, 2, 'Pedro', 'Franco', 'Escolta', '195 cms','6.000.000'),  (5, 1, 'Armando', 'Mendoza', 'Alta-Pivot', '200 cms','7.500.000') Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 2 0.000 sec

Comment: En el segundo Insert podemos observar que tiene **7 columnas pero 8 values** (2, 1, 'Pedro', 'José', 'Roa', 'Base', '198 cms','7.000.000')

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. En mysql tratá de no insertar ids. ID_Partido, id_Jugadores, ID_Equipos te recomiendo que lo pongas como autonumérico. A menos que lo vayas a clusterizar (ya que ahí tenés problemas de colisiones, y vas a tener que usar otra cosa para el autoincrement). Pero si lo vas a tener en una única instancia, te recomiendo que los ids sean AUTOINCREMENT y no los insertes nunca a mano. Es tu primary key, en tu caso es lo único que va a diferenciar una row con respecto al resto. Asegurate de que los ids sean siempre distintos (para evitar dolores de cabeza futuros)
2. en el query de Partidos tenés 6 campos definidos, pero estás tratando de insertar 7.
3. El de Jugadores no sé que problema tiene, quizás esté en los tipos de dato. ¿Son todos VARCHAR menos FK_id_Equipos?

Answer (score 0):

El número de columnas y valores si coincide. Tal vez el error este en las columnas **Altura** y **Salario** de la tabla **Jugadores**, ya que en altura colocas '210 cms'. Si ese campo es un *Integer* pues eso dará error por poner 'cm'. Igual con Salario ya que los valores tienen los puntos de separación de miles.